# Roman Numeral to integer value using xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

Is there any function to convert roman number to integer like format-number function can change integer number to roman number. As i am working on conversion a roman number to integer. if there is no function than i have to handle this in templates.

Comment: Roman to integer is a very simple function, can you add a simple function of your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have handle this through writing own function, but there is an issue that it is not validate the input value such as (VII or IVII is same) but output is correct.

**XSLT**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"           
    xmlns:number="http://dummy" version="2.0" >

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        (<xsl:value-of select="number:RomanToInteger('MMXVII', 0)"/>)
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="number:RomanToInteger">
        <xsl:param name="romannumber"/>
        <xsl:param name="followingvalue"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'CM')">
                <xsl:value-of select="900 + number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-2), 900)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'M')">
                <xsl:value-of select="1000+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-1), 1000)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'CD')">
                <xsl:value-of select="400+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-2), 400)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'D')">
                <xsl:value-of select="500+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-1), 500)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'XC')">
                <xsl:value-of select="90+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-2), 90)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'C')">
                <xsl:value-of select="(if(100 ge number($followingvalue)) then 100 else -100)+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-1), 100)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'XL')">
                <xsl:value-of select="40+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-2), 40)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'L')">
                <xsl:value-of select="50+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-1), 50)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'IX')">
                <xsl:value-of select="9+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-2), 9)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'X')">
                <xsl:value-of select="(if(10 ge number($followingvalue)) then 10 else -10) + number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-1), 10)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'IV')">
                <xsl:value-of select="4+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-2), 4)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'V')">
                <xsl:value-of select="5+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-1), 5)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($romannumber,'I')">
                <xsl:value-of select="(if(1 ge number($followingvalue)) then 1 else -1)+ number:RomanToInteger(substring($romannumber,1,string-length($romannumber)-1), 1)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```